Expression of voltage value at any point on a resistor plate
After applying different voltages V1 and V2 to the horizontal and vertical axes of a square plate with appropriate resistance values, and measuring the voltage value at a random point, how can this value be expressed in terms of V1, V2 and the coordinates of the corresponding xy point? First of all, I think I can model it like the picture, and it seems to be related to Poisson equation, but I'm not sure.


Paradoxically, the simplest solution occurs between two points of an infinite plane, with infinitesimal resistors. For a finite situation like yours, the edge effects make a mess of a nice analytic solution. Do you want to turn the handle on this 5x5 array and be done, or come up with a general solution for NxN? Do you want an exact solution, or a good approximation that you approach in the continuous case? I suspect lcapy (a python symbolic netlist solver) would give you an equation for any specific point, but it might be humungeous.

My final goal is to create a rectangular (it could be a different shape if simpler, but I think a rectangular shape is the simplest) shape with V1 (DC or AC) at the top left and V2 (DC or AC) at the bottom right. ) is applied, the voltage value of an arbitrary point is measured, and then a circuit is constructed that receives this voltage value as input and outputs the x and y coordinates of this point as two outputs. I think it has to be a solution for continuous cases, and I don't know yet whether an exact solution or an approximate solution is needed.

Have you tried using a simulator to find out the levels at different co-ordinates? I suspect that your idea will only work using two voltage sources that are AC and have differing temporal characteristics.

If this is for a real 'XY spotter', then the inverse problem might be easier to manage. A current is injected into a point in the plane. You then read the current out at each of a number of grounded points around the periphery - typically they are grounded with virtual ground amplifiers, that hold their input at ground, while generating an output voltage proportional to the current flowing in. Electrical tomography reconstruction. I suspect circular, with maximum symmetry, would yield the best reconstruction per receive channel.

Did you mean to have a ground in the lower left hand corner?

The ground or other voltage is necessary to break the symmetry so to be able to measure both directions. @MathKeepsMeBusy

Without the ground in the lower left, the array has only one voltage source, (V2-V1) form corner to corner. It means the resolution around R15/16 will be inferior to that around R33/34. It suggests that triangluar symmetry might be better, as there are three electrical contacts to the sheet

Without the ground the voltage is the same along any line perpendicular to the v1v2 diagonal. Furthermore, any voltage measured to ground would be mostly common mode without the ground in the corner.

thank you all for the comments;
@Andyaka yes I actually simulated the circuit in the image with various AC or DC V1 and V2's but realized it's quite complex to generalize it with V1 V2 x and y.

@Neil_UK using currents is a completely new idea... maybe I could think of it.

@RussellH Yes I meant to have the ground, as I wanted to be able to measure both directions.
this is how all this turned out to be- I thought that if I could spot the xy coordinates real time, then using the xy mode of oscilloscope, it would work as a memo pad. But as a dumb undergrad student, I at first imagined voltages from x and y axes would just add up on (x,y) (when V1=4 and V2=6+6sin(wt); then V(x,y)=(x/L_x)4+(y/L_y)(6+6sin(wt))), and built the circuit on breadboard that gives out x and y as output when V(x,y)=(x/L_x)4+(y/L_y)(6+6*sin(wt)) is given as input. But recently

I realized voltages don't just simply add up; that it is quite complicated, and contemplating whether to change the topic for the term project.

Try applying a voltage from upper-left to lower right. Measure and record the probe voltage relative to the lower-right. Completely remove the voltage then apply from upper-right to lower-left. Measure and record the probe voltage relative to  the lower-left. The two measurements will pinpoint the location.

This sounds like a resistive touch screen.

@Kartman yep, memopad using oscilloscope xy mode is what I intended.
